# How to create datatables after response ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, jquery-plugins

I have a problem, I want to call the datatables here after I send the data with ajax jquery, here I am having a hard time because the datatables that I will create are server-side, for the server-side calling scripts are successful and if console.log (response) it will come out data according to the format of the datatables like this

```
draw: null
recordsFiltered: 9
recordsTotal: 9
data:(9) [{..}] (and other)
```

this is my code to send data

```
var urlajax = "<?= $this->url->get($this->router->getControllerName() . '/ajaxbynip')?>";
    $("#btn-filter").click(function(){
        var data = $('#form-filter').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:urlajax,
            type:"get",
            data:data,
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
                //how can i create datatables server-side in here?
            }
        });
    });
```

i try with this code but it's doesn't work

```
tabel = $('#ats-dt-basic-datatbles').DataTable({
                stateSave: true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
                "iDisplayLength": 50,
                "ajax":
                {
                    "url": urlajax,
                    "type": "POST"
                },
                "deferRender": true,
                "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 50],[ 5, 10, 50]],
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "no" },
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "PERAN" },
                    { "data": "action" },
                ],
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#btn-filter").click(function(){
    var data = $('#form-filter').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url:urlajax,
        type:"get",
        data:data,
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            //you can try this one --> call a function or url with ajax 
            // ==>url can be a php file like createDB.php or any function url
            // write code in specific url or php file that call from ajax url for create a database according to your passing data
            
            $.ajax({
              url: url,
              type:"POST",
              data:response,
              success:function(response){
                 console.log(response);
          
              }
            });
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: result in my first ajax is data for create datatables, why i need ajax again in first response?

Comment: ok than you can use one ajax for create db. i was throught first ajax call another url.